# Compare and aggregate indicators at different geographic scale

Tags: modeling, geostatistics, composite, geography

I encountered a problem in developing an aggregation model of several indicators. Almost all the indicators are at a small geographical scale (admin2 / Provinces), but one is at larger geographical scale (admin1 / Region - that contains several admin2 provinces).

The final aggregation should maintain the "admin2 / province" scale, and aggregating the "admin1 region indicator" without any processing, will cause distortion in the smaller granularity level.

Is there a way I can solve this at indicator level (maybe weighting using territory extension / population)? Or should I rather work on the "final" aggregation, mitigating the distortion effect of this indicator via attributing less weight in the final aggregation model?

As I believe there is no ideal solution, I am testing several ideas for the moment.